# Chrome tries to switch to SSL on non SSL site

Tags: centos7

I have a test server within my local LAN and I can connect to the php info page

http://10.128.0.2/info.php

I have mapped port 8080 to the local ip address above to port 80

When I try to connect with chrome (or firefox) from an external ip address the address bar changes to https and I see this error

This site can’t provide a secure connection
XX.XX.XX.XX sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The test server is CentOS with Apache

Comment: Have you watched the protocol exchange in the Network section of the Developer's Tools in the browser? You should be able to see whether your browser is requesting SSL or the server is doing a redirect.

Comment: Hi Terry. No, how do I do that?

Comment: In chrome: three dots button -> more tools -> developer tools -> network, then open the web page you're trying to get.

Comment: It shows a 301 redirect on the info.php

Comment: Now you get to go find out if it's your server or web page that's doing the 301. 8-)

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Fri, 12 Oct 2018 20:12:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/info.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181779/discussion-between-stephen-bouffe-and-terry-carmen).

Comment: As the response says nginx it must be the server